# A practical issue in the code of HackerRank Restaurant problem

Tags: python

**Problem Statement**

Martha is interviewing at Subway. One of the rounds of the interview requires her to cut a bread of size $\ell \times b$ into smaller identical pieces such that each piece is a square having maximum possible side length with no left over piece of bread.

$\ell$ and $b$ denote the length and breadth of the bread, respectively.

The way I approached it:

```python
def restaurant(l, b):
    area = l * b
    list1 = []
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(area)) + 1):
        d = i * i
        a = area % d
        if a == 0:
            list1.append(d)
    list1.sort(reverse=True)
    return area // list1[0]
```

But this code is failing 11 of 12 test cases.

What is my mistake?

Comment: For $l = 3$ and $b = 4$, your solution gives answer $4$; however the optimal solution is $1$.

Comment: Please explain your solution and why you believe it is a solution.

Comment: The first error is not stating the required result explicitly.